# Unable to get text from TextView in android

Tags: android, textview

i have made the following function which is used to update the TextView( by getting old text in this textview and new string s and then concatenating and placing it in textview) in my calculator app.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView displayTv;
    EditText inputEt;
    Button clearButton, numberButton, equalButton;
    double answer=0,operand;
    String operation;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayTv = findViewById(R.id.input_tv);
        displayTv.setText("");
        inputEt = findViewById(R.id.input_et);
        clearButton = findViewById(R.id.clear_bt);
        reset();



    }
   void updateTv(String s){
        String text = displayTv.getText().toString();
        Log.d("test",text);
        displayTv.setText(text+s);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that even if textview has any string previously, using this function replaces the old string in textview with new String "s" intead of updating.
Basically the String "text" is empty and so no log is printed.
please help me.

Comment: Nowhere in your code do I see where you are calling the method  `updateTv()` and the string "s"  is not defined anywhere.

Comment: i havent included the code where i use this function but basically it is called in another function that is in turn called on button click.
also note that string s is an argument passed to this function.

Answer (score 0):

Use append() instead of setText() as done below -

```
void updateTv(String s){
    String text = displayTv.getText().toString();
    Log.d("test",text);
    displayTv.append(" " + s);
}
```

and call updateTv() method as required.

Comment: Using the `append` method is definitely the right way to do what the OP is wanting, but I think he wants to append only the string "s" to what is already there. Your code would append the "text"  part again. What the OP really wants is : `displayTv.append(s);`

Comment: Yes, in a hurry i didn't noticed that. But now i have made changes in the code.

Comment: No Barns , the want to retain the previous text and add new text s and display i.e. text+s and not only s or text

Comment: You are setting displayTv.setText("");. This will remove the text set through xml file. So your xml text will be retained if you remove this line. And then you use append, the s (string) will be added to your xml text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
    void updateTv(String s){
    StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
    stringBuffer.append(displayTv.getText().toString() +"  "+ s);
    displayTv.setText(stringBuffer);   
}
```

if want to clear last string then used set

```
        displayTv.setText("");
```

Comment: the things is inspite of some text in the textview (i.e. displayTv) the "displayTv.getText().toString()" is not returning anything...

Comment: In this case first set text in textview into xml file in or programatically set by setText then it give some value.

Comment: already did that. you see i used displayTv.setText(""); in the onCreate Method

Comment: @KebrumOtis ::  setting  `displayTv.setText("");` is setting the `TextView` content to an empty string which is...empty. No text! Adding the string "s" to and empty string is always going to be just what ever "s"  contains.